# Powershell script using another user account

Tags: powershell, credentials

I'm not very good with powershell (to be honest, I'm bad !) but I need to do a script which download pictures and store them in a specific shared folder. I can download the pictures easily, but the folder where I need to store them is protected and there's is only one user (created specifically) who has access on it.

So my question is : how can I configure my script to use this user credentials ? I searched on the net, but I can't understand. As I said, I'm not a powershell user, and I use OS X at home, so I'm not even good with Windows rights and permissions. So a clear and easy answer would be really appreciated !

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Invoke-Command` command with the `-Credential` and `-ScriptBlock` parameters to launch a PowerShell ScriptBlock as a different account. I believe that you will also need to enable PSRemoting in order for `Invoke-Command` command to work, even on the local system.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential;
$ScriptBlock = { Copy-Item -Path c:\test\test.txt -Destination c:\test2\test.txt; };
Invoke-Command -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock;
```

A more complicated solution would be to use the `Start-Process` cmdlet with the `-Credential` parameter, to kick off an external executable under an alternate credential. If you just want to kick off PowerShell code though, you're better off using `Invoke-Command`.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential;
$Executable = 'c:\path\to\file.exe';
Start-Process -FilePath $Executable -Credential $Credential -Wait -NoNewWindow;
```

Comment: Get-Credential method seems great but (and I forgot to say it, sorry) the script will be scheduled, so if all could be done with command line, I would be the best ! I don't know how scheduling works, however. I'm sorry, I'm not very good, but it's my first real script !

Comment: If you're going to use this script through the task scheduler, you can specify run-as credentials when you set up the task.

Comment: In fact, I'm not going to schedule it, I will give the script to somebody who will do the scheduling and stuff. So, basically, the credentials isn't my job ? That's it ?

Comment: Yes, that's all there is to it. :)

Comment: Ok great ! But thank you for your answer, it was useful. I finally understood how-to use Get-Credential :)